# Query boolean with multiple parameters

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

As stated in the docs(http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/),i´m trying to write a query like this:

```
public Page<AnyObject> findByActiveTrueAndUser(Boolean ativo, User user, Pageable pageable);
```

But I´m getting the following error:What could be wrong?

Parameter value [true] did not match expected type [.com.User]

Comment: it´s just a POJO annotated with JPA annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method name

> findByActiveTrueAndUser(...

states your query should filter by `active` = `true` and User. User being the only parameter to filter by, since active = true is implied by method name. So it should be

```
findByActiveTrueAndUser(User user, Pageable pageable);
```

otherwise, change your method name to

> findByActiveAndUser(...

to dynamically filter on `active` and User.

Answer (score 1):

By having `findByActiveTrueAndUser` spring data expects only one parameter (`User` in this case), because you have told already spring to give you ones which are active (`findByActiveTrue` part).

Therefore as you are passing boolean as first parameter, it can't match to the expected `User` type of parameter.

So change your method signature either to

```
public Page<AnyObject> findByActiveAndUser(Boolean active, User user, Pageable pageable);
```

or

```
 public Page<AnyObject> findByActiveTrueAndUser(User user, Pageable pageable);
```